# Laravel install on Fedora 33

Tags: laravel, fedora, laravel-sail, fedora-33

I am trying to create a new Laravel project on my Fedora 33 system as per:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-linux

I run the command and get the following output:

```
[glen@localhost gclark18]$ sudo curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash

 _                               _
| |                             | |
| |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
| |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
| |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
|______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|

Warning: TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.
    Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./example-app"
    Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.14)
    
                                  
  [ErrorException]            
  mkdir(): Permission denied  
                              

    create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]

bash: line 16: cd: example-app: No such file or directory

Get started with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

I am not sure why it would not have permission as this is my a folder in my home directory that I have full permissions to.

Comment: same here. did you solve?

Comment: @mdmundo I recall this issue being related to Fedora not using docker (they use an alternative) and so I could not get sail working.